# Changing servername in nginx causes failures

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, https

I'm running an installation of a web app which uses nginx for its HTTPS and apache to serve content.

I've just finished installing an upgraded version on a new machine but I'm running into a weird problem.

Everything is fine when I use the URL newapplication.mydomaincom. However, when I try to go live by switching everything to application.mydomain.com, it doesn't work - I just get the test "Welcome to nginx!" page.

My application.conf file is below and note that if I change every instance of "application.mydomain.com" to "newapplication.mydomain.com" then it works perfectly well - I can enter "newapplication.mydomain.com" in a browser and be redirected to HTTPS. However, when using "application.mydomain.com", it fails. I can enter "application.mydomain.com:18804" and this works (as per my apache config).

Nginx config file:

```
    upstream application {

            server 127.0.0.1:18805;

    }


    server {

            listen 18804;

            location / {

                    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

            }

    }




    server {

            listen 80;

            location / {

                    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

            }

    }



    server {

            listen 443 ssl;

            server_name application.mydomain.com;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;

            error_log /var/log/nginx/application-errors.log;

            ssl on;

            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/my.key;

            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/my.crt;

            ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


            client_max_body_size 0;



            location / {

                    proxy_set_header Host $host;

                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                    proxy_pass http://redmine;

            }

    }

    server {
        listen 18804;
        server_name application.mydomain.com;

        return 301 https://application.mydomain.com$uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name application.mydomain.com;

        return 301 https://application.mydomain$uri;
}
```

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:18805>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/application/public
  ServerName application.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
  ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../tmp/stop.txt -f
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=503,L]

<Directory /var/www/html/application/public/>
  AllowOverride all
  # MultiViews must be turned off.
  Options -MultiViews
</Directory>

  ErrorLog logs/application_3.3.3_log

</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I's confusing that simply changing the server name is doing this.

Comment: Totally unrelated but... RC4, seriously?

Comment: I inherited this from a previous staff member and haven't had a chance to study ciphers as this is quite new to me. However your comment led me to do some reading and I have removed this line from the config, so thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a caching issue - a silly oversight on my part. Cleared cache, all fine.